# XSL Creation for the given input and output

Tags: xml, xslt

Hi I have following XML as input to my xsl,Is there any online tool to do the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent att1="2012-11-30"
   att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="1032">
    <Child1 att1="0"/>
    <Child2>
        <Child3 CodeShort="1032" CodeType="NODE" CodeValue="Rohith"/>
        <Child3 CodeShort="1032" CodeType="NODE" CodeValue="Sachin"/>
        <Child3 CodeShort="1032" CodeType="NODE" CodeValue="Rahul"/>
    </Child2>
</Parent>
```

I need to iterate over child3 times and copy only the Parent tag that many times and replace the att4 of parent with the Child3 CodeValue every time my out should look like,facing problem while transforming the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multiApi>
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Rohith" ></Parent>
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Sachin" ></Parent>
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Rahul" ></Parent>
</multiApi>
```

Please let us know what xsl i need to use for the same,please help me if there is any online tool to do the same.

I need to iterate over child3 times and copy only the Parent tag that many times and replace the att4 of parent with the Child3 CodeValue every time

**EDIT:** xsl which we tried unable to come at concrete solution though

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <mutiApi>
            <xsl:for-each select="parent/child2/child3">
                <xsl:copy-of select="/parent" />
                <xsl:attribute name="Node">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@CodeValue" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </mutiApi>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your xml is not well formed, maybe it's just a typo, but you don't have a root node in it..

Comment: Can you also edit your question to show any XSLT you have already tried, please?

Comment: @Oscar what xml you are refering to output or input

Comment: xsl which we tried unable to come at concrete solution though  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<mutiApi>
<xsl:for-each select="parent/child2/child3">
<xsl:copy-of select="/parent"/>
<xsl:attribute name="Node">
<xsl:value-of select="./@CodeValue"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
</mutiApi>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Is the expected output correct too? The output shows `att4="Rohith"` but the XSLT you have shown (in comments) looks like you want to create a new attribute called `Node` to store this value.

Comment: Tim it is sample code which I am trying but the intention was to get att4="rohith" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to copy the `<Parent>` node along with it's attributes, you can create the `<Parent>` node and iterate over it's attributes. For attribute `att4`, you can conditionally check it's name and replace the value with that of `@CodeValue`.

Below is the XSLT that can help provide the desired output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Child2">
        <multiApi>
            <xsl:for-each select="Child3">
                <xsl:variable name="codeVal" select="@CodeValue" />
                <Parent>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/Parent/@*">
                        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name(.) = 'att4'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$codeVal" />
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Parent>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </multiApi>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<multiApi>
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Rohith" />
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Sachin" />
    <Parent att1="2012-11-30" att2="Y" att3="11404262" att4="Rahul" />
</multiApi>
```

Comment: Thanks we wrote similar xsl